# Postgres alternative to MySQL Connector/J continueBatchOnError

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

When trying to run a batch on postgres it seems that a failure in one of the jobs prevents the completion of the batch. In MySQL and ORACLE continueBatchOnError flag is on the batch completes and its results can be retrieved after calling

`BatchUpdateException.getUpdateCounts`

So is there an option to allow this functionality in postgres jdbc?

Comment: I doubt it. A single batch is always a single transaction. And per definition all statements in a transaction must be successful to be able to commit the transaction. Having a transaction where some statements are successful and some fail violates the most basic principle of a transactional database.